# Can't fetch data from Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk

I made a [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) plugin for social network authentification using Facebook, Twitter, Google, and LinkedIn. The whole plugin works 100% with no bug or error, but lately I tried to login via Facebook and I found myself unable to fetch data from the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Here is what I've done.

*AuthController Facebook action*

```
public function facebook(){
    $facebookObj = SocialAuth::init('facebook');
    $facebookLoginUrl = $facebookObj->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => SocialAuth::getConfig('facebook','permissions'),
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'redirect_uri' => SocialAuth::getConfig('facebook','redirect_uri')));
    $this->redirect($facebookLoginUrl);
}
```

*AuthController callback action*

```
public function callback(){
    $facebookObj = SocialAuth::init('facebook');
    $facebookInfo = $facebookObj->getUser();

    if ($facebookInfo) { // $facebookInfo always return 0 (it was working before >_<)
        // ..
    }
}
```

***$facebookInfo*** debug informations

```
/app/Plugin/SocialAuth/Controller/AuthsController.php (line 104)
object(Facebook) {
    [protected] sharedSessionID => null
    [protected] kSupportedKeys => array(
        (int) 0 => 'state',
        (int) 1 => 'code',
        (int) 2 => 'access_token',
        (int) 3 => 'user_id'
    )
    [protected] DROP_QUERY_PARAMS => array(
        (int) 0 => 'code',
        (int) 1 => 'state',
        (int) 2 => 'signed_request'
    )
    [protected] appId => '503845519711145'
    [protected] appSecret => '--secret--'
    [protected] user => (int) 0
    [protected] signedRequest => null
    [protected] state => '59e2aba0d18dcc166d8c4aef0f1668c9'
    [protected] accessToken => '{app-id}|{app-secret}'
    [protected] fileUploadSupport => false
    [protected] trustForwarded => false
    [protected] allowSignedRequest => false
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Dude, you publicly posted your app secret – so go & reset it ASAP. (Yes, you replaced the `appSecret` with `--secret--` … but look at the second part of your `accessToken`, that should look very familiar …) As for your problem, the Facebook PHP SDK returning 0 for a user id is a problem that has been discussed a lot already – I don’t know whether SocialAuth is using that or not, but you should be able to get some clues form those discussions. And if not, ask the provider of SocialAuth to fix it (it’s a paid-for component after all, if we are talking about the same SocialAuth here, right?)

Comment: SocialAuth its just a plugin that i made by myself .

Comment: This is going to be really difficult for us to fix - since you are using a home-made plugin which we cannot see the source code to. Does your plugin use the Facebook PHP SDK? What did you change before it stopped working? Does your plugin successfully exchange the code for an access token as part of the oauth process (asking this because the access token above looks like an app access token and not a user access token)

Comment: My plugin use to exchange the right user access token , but that was before , what problems might provoke this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to update to the latest Facebook-php-SDK and the problem was fixed...

I also had to upload the [fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt) file.